# Why do I have a Thunderbolt 4 controller but no port

Tags: thunderbolt, lspci

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IAU7 laptop, and have only used Ubuntu for a month, so sorry if I ask something stupid.
My computer has a usbc 3.2 port, but no thunderbolt 4 ports. However, if I run lspci this is in the list:

```
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 04)
```

Does this mean I could somehow install a thunderbolt 4 port on my computer? If not, why does this show up?

Comment: I'm guessing that ubuntu thinks that your 3.2 is a 4.0.. Since they both achieve the same transfer speeds...

Comment: maybe.. but thunderbolt speeds are 40 gbps while usb c is 20 gbps

Comment: What symbol is printed on the side of the laptop near the "USB 3.2" port? If it's a arrow shaped like a lightning bolt, then it is a thunderbolt port.